# I have two views that are really similar. How can I "superclass" them?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to design a Django application that facilitates the lending and borrowing of musical instruments between musicians.

I have one template page that includes the form to post an instrument for lending or borrowing, and another template that includes the form for searching for available listings.

The difference between the two views other than the templates that are rendered (slightly different designs and buttons) is the name of the form they add to the context (i.e. `PostForm()` and `SearchForm()`)

Basically, I have two views with almost completely the same code. This is bad practice usually.

Is there any way I can consolidate the two views into a "super-view" of sorts so that changes to one view are automatically made across both? I want to avoid duplicate code wherever possible.

Comment: This is, in fact, very straightforward to do that, maybe we can give you a best help if you provide the code of your current views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to do with Class Based Views (CBV).

For example, you may use `django.views.generic.FormView`, as follows in your `views.py`:

```
from django.views import generic

class ClassyFormView(generics.FormView):  # Of course name the view whatever you like
    # Note that I'm not setting any of the specific attributes here
    # As I am planning on overriding this view for each form's specifics

    # This is where you may override methods of the FormView
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ This method allows you to edit the context passed to the template """

        context = super(ClassyFormView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)  # Get context from FormView

        # Add variables to the context data
        context['message'] = "Hello World!"

        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """ 
        This method is called once the form has been instantiated with 
        POST data and has been validated
        """

        # Do whatever you want after the form is validated
        print(form.cleaned_data['some_field'])

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        # Do something if the form is invalid
        pass
```

You can then override your custom class, to maintain the specific things it does over `FormView`, but use the correct form class:

```
class SearchFormView(ClassyFormView):
    form_class = SearchForm

class PostFormView(ClassyFormView):
    form_class = PostForm
```

Note that you can (and probably will) also set fields such as `prefix`, `success_url`, and `template_name`, as well as override tons of other methods that may be useful!

Note that if your forms are `ModelForm`s, then you will probably want to use one of the model specific generic form views, such as `CreateView` or `UpdateView`. Using these will allow you to access the object that the form is acting on. So, after setting the correct model in the class, your `form_valid` method may look like this:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    # Do stuff here to the object before you save it
    # Such as altering or setting fields
    self.object.some_field = "I'm a string"
    self.object.save()
```

I can't explain *everything* about CBV, or even the class based form views here, so make sure to look at further **documentation**:

[Django Class-Based-View Inspector](http://ccbv.co.uk/) is a really awesome site that not many people seem to know about! Usually easier than diving into the source code.

Relevant Django docs:

- [CBVs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/)
- [Generic editing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

---

Decided to add a few more details that may be helpful.

The generic views specify defaults for their class attributes, but unless you're being *really* generic, it's usually a good idea to override them. Some explanation on the specific attributes:

- `prefix` specifies a prefix for the form. Useful in cases where using multiple forms.

  - Defaults to `None`.
  - If you require more advanced logic, you can set the prefix by returning it in the `get_prefix()` method.
- `success_url` specifies where the form will redirect to on success. For the model form views, this will default to the model's `get_absolute_url()`

  - Can be set by returning success url in `get_success_url()` method
- `template_name` specifies the name of the template that the view will display upon a get request

  - Can be set by returning template name in `get_template_name()` method.

Configuring URLs for CBV is easy, too. Use the `as_view()` method as follows:

```
url(r'^some_url/', SearchFormView.as_view(), name="some-url")
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So if I create a class based view, what do I put in the URLconf? Until now, all my views have been methods in the `views.py` file

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention that. You would configure your url in the same way as you normally would, but use the method `as_view()` on the class. Updated answer